# FullPage.js paddingTop issues on different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I am using `fullpage.js` for a website I am building but am having a lot of issues with setting the `paddingTop` setting and the screen displaying properly.

For example:

Here is Chrome on a 13" Macbook Air http://cl.ly/image/1D2P1S3Z291W

Here is the screen on an iPad 2 (vertical) view: http://cl.ly/image/1m2M3H1E2E3n

The problem is the gap at the top. The gap appears on screens larger than 13" laptops too

Here is my JavaScript:

```
    $('.fullPage').fullpage({
        responsive: 768,
        autoScrolling: false,
        anchors: ['home', 'customResearch', 'onlineCommunities', 'buzzSection', 'ourStorySection', 'howWeWorkSection', 'aliciaProfile', 'patProfile', 'clientsSection', 'experienceSection', 'contactUs'],
        easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
        fixedElements: '#mainNav',
        fitToSection: false,
        verticalCentered: true,
        loopHorizontal: false,
        scrollOverflow: false,
        css3: true,
        paddingTop: '147px',
        resize: false,
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {

            if($.inArray(anchorLink, ['aliciaProfile', 'patProfile'])) {
                var parent = $('[data-anchor="' + anchorLink + '"]');

                if(isElementInViewport(parent)) {
                    animateProfileSubImages(parent);
                }
            }

            var expTblCell = $('#experience').find('.fp-tableCell');
            $(expTblCell).attr('style', '');
        }
    });
```

There is no padding on the HTML body. I am just needing the top image section to sit directly underneath the nav on all screens (regardless of screen size)

Comment: It would be easier to know what's going on if you give us a link to your site or a way to reproduce the issue. Otherwise... its gonna be difficult for you to get any answer.

Comment: https://staging-marketing360.herokuapp.com - the build on the server right now, works, but I had to do some custom JS wizardry to adjust the margin for the top section.

Comment: In that example you are not using padding at all. And you have `margin-top: -147px;` in the `home1` element...

Comment: @Alvaro a new build is out here http://staging-marketing360.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I still seeing "padding:0px" on the section. Please, add the unminified version of your fullpage.js initialization.

Comment: And... use `verticalCentered:false`...

Comment: The problem with not using `verticalCentered: false` is that content becomes hidden behind other sections on the page... Here is the JS un-minified for the site: https://gist.github.com/dennismonsewicz/f892631e344678a0c14d ... and I pushed out another build to the server that uses `verticalCentered: false`